# Saving Data form in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, save, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I had a problem with saving my data "my form does not passed a correct array", I want to know what is the error in my code  (After reading the cookbook)I understand the array that passed to saving method should be like this

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'value' => '',
        'id' => '',
        'indicator_id' => '283',
        'report_year_id' => '7',
        'Assurance' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1',
            (int) 1 => '2',
            (int) 2 => '3',
            (int) 3 => '4',
            (int) 4 => '5'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'value' => '',
        'id' => '',
        'indicator_id' => '283',
        'report_year_id' => '6',
        'Assurance' => ''))
```

but when I debug my code I found that the data passed to saving method :

```
array(
    'currentOrg' => array(
        'id' => '40'
    ),
    'IndicatorDatum' => array(
        '$cn' => array(
            'id' => '',
            'comment' => '',
            'reference' => ''
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'value' => '',
            'Assurance' => ''
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'value' => '',
            'Assurance' => ''
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'value' => '',
            'Assurance' => ''
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'value' => '',
            'Assurance' => ''
        ),
```

**My form :**

```
echo $this->DashboardForm->create('IndicatorDatum',array(
    'url' => array('controller'=>'indicator_data','action'=>'edit_group', 'dashboard'=>true, $thisGroup['IndicatorGroup']['id']),
    'novalidate'=>true
    ));
            <?  $cn = 0; 
            foreach ($years as $year) :
            echo $this->Form->hidden("IndicatorDatum.$cn.id");
            echo $this->Form->hidden("IndicatorDatum.$cn.state");
            echo $this->Form->input("IndicatorDatum.$cn.indicator_id",array(
                                                'type'=>'hidden', 'default'=>$iid
                                            )); 
        echo $this->Form->input("IndicatorDatum.$cnt.report_year_id",array(
                                            'type'=>'hidden', 'default'=>$yid
                                        )); 
            echo $this->Form->input('IndicatorDatum.$cn.value');                                   
            echo $this->Form->input("IndicatorDatum.$cn.Assurance", array('style'=>'width: 165px;',
                                                        'type'=>'select',
                                                        'multiple'=>true, 'options' => $assurances, 'selected' => $selected,'label' => false));
            $cn++;
            endforeach;

     echo $this->Form->submit(__('Save All'));

    ?>
```

**My controller :**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')|| $this->request->is('put')) {
            $data = debug($this->request->data);
                        if ($this->IndicatorDatum->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The indicator data has been saved'), 'flash/success');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'edit_group',$group_id));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The indicator data could not be saved. Please verify the fields highlighted in red and try again.'), 'flash/error');
            }
        }
```

> The Error 'UPDATE'

I go  DATABASE ERROR
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') GROUP BY s.state, s.indicator_datum_id) AS `LatestStateUpdate` ON' at line 4

SQL Query: SELECT `IndicatorDatum`.`id`, `IndicatorDatumUpdate`.*, (CONCAT(`IndicatorDatum`.`indicator_id`,'_',`IndicatorDatum`.`report_year_id`)) AS `IndicatorDatum__indexKey` FROM `astest`.`indicator_data` AS `IndicatorDatum` INNER JOIN (SELECT u.indicator_datum_id, MAX(u.created) as update_date, s.state FROM indicator_datum_states s INNER JOIN indicator_datum_updates u on u.id = s.indicator_datum_update_id WHERE s.indicator_datum_id IN () GROUP BY s.state, s.indicator_datum_id) AS `LatestStateUpdate` ON (`IndicatorDatum`.`id` = `LatestStateUpdate`.`indicator_datum_id` AND `IndicatorDatum`.`state` = `LatestStateUpdate`.`state`) INNER JOIN `astest`.`indicator_datum_updates` AS `IndicatorDatumUpdate` ON (`IndicatorDatumUpdate`.`indicator_datum_id` = `LatestStateUpdate`.`indicator_datum_id` AND `IndicatorDatumUpdate`.`created` = `LatestStateUpdate`.`update_date`) WHERE `IndicatorDatum`.`id` = (NULL)

Comment: Hi, data is not save in data base right ? Check the input field name and table field are same ?

Comment: yes, It is the same , I am wondering why I have a wrong passed array ?

Comment: let me know ? what error do u got ?

Comment: This is what i got when trying to save the data  (The indicator data could not be saved. Please verify the fields highlighted in red and try again.)

Comment: What you updated in question ?

Comment: You need to updated the field or insert ?

Answer (score 1):

It's throwing the error because of your empty `IN()` and doesn't appear to be related to the `saveAll()`:

```
WHERE s.indicator_datum_id IN ()
```

Where is this `SELECT` being built?  I suggest checking if it's empty first before building that condition.

(It's hard to say where that is coming from - it doesn't look like it's coming from any of the provided code.)